# Insert data from one table to another table

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have on table T1 with data

```
RK1
RK3
RK5
RK2
```

i want to insert data in table T2 from T1 with output like

```
col1   col2
11      RK1
12      RK2
13      RK3
14      RK5
```

With col2 sorted?

could you please write sql query for the same?

Comment: in table T2 col11 should be added with these values and it should not be identity column.
Col2 is coming from Table T1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an insert:

```
   INSERT INTO YourTable (Col1, Col2)
   SELECT 11, RK1
   UNION SELECT 12, RK2
   UNION SELECT 13, RK3
   UNION SELECT 14, RK5
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 and above

```
INSERT TABLE2
   (col1, col2)
SELECT
   'I' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TheCol) AS varchar(10)), TheCol
FROM
   TABLE1
ORDER BY
   TheCol
```

Comment: Hi,

It should be start with 11

Comment: @Vijay Sharma: why not try to adapt my solution?